# Jsoup elemento sem id

Tags: jsoup

Bom, estou querendo usar JSoup pra pegar uma tabela de um site e mostrar no aplicativo. O problema é que essa tabela não tem id. Como fazer pra pegar essa tabela e exibir no app?
Aqui tá o site:http://warface.uol.com.br/suporte/lista-de-punidos

Answer (score 1):

Com o JSoup, a busca por elementos não precisa ser exclusivamente por Id. Você pode também fazer buscar por CSS Selectors. Assim:

```
Elements elements = document.select("#main > div > div.conteudo > table");
```